# Setting Layout Constraint Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

This screen Layout is by default in English

and now when I change language to arabic from my app it should like this

then screen which I want to like this on runtime

[image]

so how I set constraint programmatically in objective c for this to be like screen 2 this on runtime .

Comment: Just check the language of your phone programmatically and then change the layout of text.  For example. if ([myLang isEqualToString:@"English"]) {
    self.myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft; // this is for English
} else {
    self.myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight; // this is for Arabic
}

Comment: yeah I did it for Label but how to set image to right as shown above in the screen @Nilesh Jha

Comment: If you use leading/trailing constraints not left/right constraints the the layout should adapt to your locale automatically

Comment: yeah I know that but here I don't know how to do it for images, @Paulw11

Comment: If you have the constraint so that the leading edge of the image is constrained to the leading edge of the superview Andre the trailing edge of the image is constrained to the leading edge of the text and the trailing edge of the text is aligned to the trailing edge of the superview then it will render left-to-right or right-to-left depending on the locale without you needing to make any changes.

Comment: UIImage* defaultImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"art.png"];
UIImage* flipImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:sourceImage.CGImage scale:1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
myImageview.image = flipImage;